# Equation whose solution is a finite tower of $2's$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, power-towers

What equation has a finite power tower of $2's,$ as it's solution:

$$ x=2^{{2^{2}}^{\cdot\cdot\cdot}}.$$

I tried to reverse engineer the solution, back into an equation, so I started with a toy model of the solution:

$x=2^{2^{2}}.$

I took multiple logarithms on both sides and then decided to rest.

Comment: Okay it's as many 2s as you want

Comment: @DonThousand They have tons of applications of it... somewhere with the name of Power Series. I don't know much, but Ackerman Functions and Knuth's Arrow-Up Notation are some terms which are related to this. And Obviously, it doesn't converge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a simple one, but this is not really exciting.

We have,

$$x = {{{2^{2}}^{2}}^{2}}^{....}$$

Now, I will take logarithms on both sides, just like you did, with base $2$. So,

$$\log_2x = \log_2({{{2^{2}}^{2}}^{2}}^{....})$$

$$\implies \log_2x = {{{2^{2}}^{2}}^{2}}^{....} \text{[The power tower is infinite.]}$$

$$\implies\log_2 x = x \implies 2^x = x$$

That's it.

Wolfram Alpha also shows an appropriate solution expressed with **Lambert W Function**:

$$x = \frac{W_n(-\log(2))}{\log(2)}, \text{where n} \in \Bbb{Z}$$.

**Eisenstein** confirmed a Power Tower can be expressed in the form :

$$ {{{a^{a}}^{a}}^{a}}^{....} = \frac{W_n(-\log(a))}{\log(a)}, \text{where n} \in \Bbb{Z}$$

So The Solution of WolframAlpha confirms $$x = {{{2^{2}}^{2}}^{2}}^{....}$$

Source : [Lambert W Function : WolframAlpha](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)

Comment: Op asked about a finite power tower.

Comment: @Willam Isn't the same concept used for the finite one?

Comment: And moreover, when I answered the question, it wasn't edited and it said "a power tower of 2s" instead of "**finite** power tower of 2s"

Answer (score 1):

$$ x - 2^{{2^{2}}^{\cdot\cdot\cdot}} = 0.$$

Comment: Actually this is quite humourous to me, even if it's absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the easiest equation that you can find for this is quite beautiful actually.

Consider,
$$
   x = 2^x
$$
This is based on the simple observation, which is quite useful in such infinite series, that there is an exact copy of x in the exponential of 2. This recursive observation would lead you to writing the RHS as $ 2^x$.

Comment: Op asked about a finite power tower.

Answer (score 0):

Solving this equation for $x$ gives the desired solution:

$f(x)=2^{(2^2A)}=\frac{1}{A};$ $A=\frac{1}{\log_2(\log_2(\log_2(x)))}.$

Here the nested logarithms can be nested further to give an arbitrarily high power tower.

Comment: I guess that's what we call a Polylogarithm Function.